# Meta tags currently supported and required by Google

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-tags

I know that this question has been asked before but since that was in the past, I have to ask it again. I am new to website development and I don't need a broad answer, just the important tags that are currently supported and needed.

I came to know that `keywords` meta tag is ignored by Google spiders but still some meta tags are supported. So I really just need a short list and some description.

Also isn't meta tags like `PICS` still required for content filtering? I am trying to develop a hotel website.

Answer (score 3):

No meta tags are *required* by Google. The list of *supported* ones was mentioned in a question earlier today: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en